General formula for approach speed of a limit that approaches ln(x)
I recently learned of the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left(\sqrt[n]{x}-1\right) = \ln(x),\;\; x\in\mathbb{R}^+$$
and played around with plotting $y=x\left(\sqrt[x]{a}-1\right)$ and $y=\ln(a)$ for various choices of $a$.
This led me to wondering about how to solve
$$\left|\frac{n\left(\sqrt[n]{x}-1\right)}{\ln{x}}-1\right|<\varepsilon$$ for $n$ (essentially creating a function that tells you how high $n$ needs to go for a given $x$ so that the result of $n(\sqrt[n]{x}-1)$ is within a factor of $1\pm\varepsilon$ of the limit).
I can plot $$\left|\frac{y\left(\sqrt[y]{x}-1\right)}{\ln{x}}-1\right|=\varepsilon$$ in Geogebra and WolframAlpha gives me two answers for similarly turning the inequality into an equation (apparently it doesn't like solving inequalities), but when testing those WolframAlpha answers in Geogebra with specific values for $x$ and $\varepsilon$ (thankfully Geogebra knows about ProductLog/LambertW), sometimes both answers give negative results, despite $(1+\varepsilon)\ln{x}$ being clearly between $1(\sqrt[1]{x}-1)$ and $\ln{x}$ for the $x$ in question. If I try giving $\varepsilon$ a specific value in my request to WolframAlpha, it gives several answers, partly depending on whether $x$ is negative or positive. If I try to restrict $x$ to be positive, it doesn't understand the request anymore.
Which brings me here with the hope that someone with a better grasp of the mathematics in question might be similarly intrigued by this question and find a working inequality for $n$ in terms of $x$ and $\varepsilon$.

How large must $n$ be for
$$1-\varepsilon<\frac{x^{1/n}-1}{\ln x^{1/n}}<1+\varepsilon.$$
Consider $x>1,$ leaving $x<1$ for the reader. Let $y=x^{1/n}.$ Then the inequality becomes
$$(1-\varepsilon)\ln y < y-1 < (1+\varepsilon)\ln y.$$
Using Taylor series or similar methods
$$ y-1 -\tfrac{1}{2} (y-1)^2 < \ln y < y-1.$$
Hence it is sufficient to solve
$$(1-\varepsilon)(y-1) < y-1 < (1+\varepsilon)(y-1 - \tfrac {1}{2}(y-1)^2 ).$$
Dividing by $y-1$ this becomes
$$1-\varepsilon < 1 < (1+\varepsilon)(1-\tfrac{1}{2}(y-1)).$$
The first inequality is always true and the second simplifies to
$$ y < 1 + \frac{2\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon}.$$
Using $y=x^{1/n}$ and solving for $n$ gives
$$\frac{\ln x}{\ln( 1+\tfrac{2\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} )} < n.$$
